# How do you draw a line with Java?

Tags: java, swing, draw

I'm trying to draw a line and just can't figure it out. I actually need to draw a triangle for my computer science lab. I'm very new to programming, going off of Big Java book by Horstmann. It's unclear on how to exactly draw something and I'm just not getting it. First it introduces a "EmptyFrameViewer" and says its the "essential plumping" to show a frame, which I can get to work. I have a frame pop up but have never get anything to draw on the frame. The following is my code and all I get is a 500x500 frame. Can anyone help me? I just want a line! once I have a line I'm sure I can figure out how to draw more things.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawFrame extends JComponent 
{
public void lineComponent (Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics g);
    Line2D.Double line1 = new Line2D.Double(30, 110, 80, 110);
    g2.draw(line1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setTitle("BE A LINE");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DrawFrame component = new DrawFrame();
    frame.add(component);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: try renaming your method to `paintComponent`. There is also a syntax error on first line of the method. It should read `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;`

Answer (score 1):

For custom paintings you need to use `paintComponent()` method of `JComponent`. Try to change your code with adding next lines to your code.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    lineComponent(g);
}
```

Also change `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics g);` to `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;`, because that code have compilation error.

Comment: @user3251641 Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of the method from `lineComponent` to `paintComponent`, you'll see that the line will be drawn.

Or you might want to create a separate paintComponent method where you call lineComponent.

Answer (score -2):

it is possible to draw a line that snaps like into a checkbox square then snap another line Square --------Square ---------Square ----------sqa

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).